# Angular JS $http.get returns empty data from WP REST API, but only on actual iOS device

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, wordpress-rest-api

I'm making an Ionic app that accesses a Wordpress site using the WP REST API V2 plugin. Given this code in my controller:

```
$http.get('http://www.greenfundsuriname.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/3701').then(function(response) {
    $log.log(response);
});

$http.get('http://www.greenfundsuriname.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/').then(function(response) {
    $log.log(response);
});
```

I get two perfectly fine responses on my local machine and in the iOS simulator, see:

[image]

On my actual device, the single post works fine but the posts URL gives me an empty array as the data response:

[image]

How is this possible?

Comment: Managed to get the same behavior in a browser: http://codepen.io/lensco/pen/meKEqP (first button returns empty array response, but API URL does have content)

Comment: Your code pen seems to work fine for me.

Comment: So apparently this _does_ work for several other people. I tried increasing the $http timeout, I validated the JSON, I tried it at another place on a different (faster) network, it doesn't make a difference. The Posts API route works fine in my browser, but returns an empty array when accessed via Angular $http. Other API routes are fine. Well I'll be damned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out one of the headers in the request caused this. Since my OS language is set to Dutch the Accept-Language header asked for Dutch posts in the Wordpress. Wordpress correctly returned an empty array. Other people – whose OS is set to English – get all the English Wordpress posts. Solved it like this:

```
$http.get( url, {
    headers: {'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6'}
});
```